# How can I have my python file show its mercurial tag or revision as the module version?

Tags: python, mercurial, keyword

I'd like to add a --version command line option to my python application that will show the *right* version depending on the tagged status of the command:

If the file comes from a version whose short hex ID was `abcdef01` that was tagged `TAG`, `--version` should show this:

```
MyApp Version TAG (abcdef01)
```

If the file comes from the tip, `--version` should show this:

```
MyApp (tip)
```

If the file comes from an arbitrary, untagged revision `abcdef02`, `--version` should show this:

```
MyApp (development, abcdef02)
```

Is this possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Once you activate the [keyword extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/KeywordExtension), you can have it in a variable which can be carved up for the hash.

Comment: I can't see how to get the tag name out of that, just the short version string.

Answer (score 1):

Someone pointed out the KeywordExtension, and that's definitely one route to go.

For a little more control you can create an 'update' writes what you want into a `version` file which you don't add to the repository itself.  Something like this in your repo's hgrc:

```
[hooks]
update = hg id > version.txt
```

Where `version.txt` exists in your .hgignore because you don't want to track changes to it.  Then you have your version code read that file.

The advantage to using a hook vs. the KeywordExtension is the ability to use more complex tag trolling logic.

In fact the [nearest extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/NearestExtension) might get you pretty much exactly what you want:

> The goal of the nearest mercurial
>   extension is to find the nearest
>   tag(s) from a given changeset, either
>   backward or forward in the changesets
>   history tree.
>
> By default, tags are searched backward
>   in history, but using the --contains
>   option will make it search forward. It
>   answers the following questions:
>
> On which tag this changeset is based
>   on ? (without --contains) Which tag
>   will include / contain this changeset
>   ? (with --contains) The tags are
>   searched by date, so that the nearest
>   tag in time will be reported. However,
>   the --all option will make the
>   extension search the first tag on all
>   possible branches.